# Small number of programming instructions

Tags: color, code, backgrounds, programming, console

I am writing an article and I need to insert a small number of code instructions for a topic related to computer science.
I know the existence of many packages, such as Listing, Algorithmic and so on, but they are useful only for long algorithms, while I need something simpler and quite different to an algorithm, something more similar to a console, working with one or at least very few instructions, as shown in the attached figure.

In particular I am interested in the gray background that stretches across the width of the page and does not end at the termination of the instruction, so as to simulate a real console.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to achieve this simple effect shown in the figure? Thank you very much again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This option was listed (almost verbatim) from the [`tcolorbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox) (specifically, the example under the key/option for `/tcb/every listing line`). You'll need to include/use the `listings` library (accessed via `\tcbuselibrary{listings}`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox,lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\newtcblisting{commandshell}{
  colback=black!25,
  colupper=black,
  colframe=yellow!75!black,
  listing only,
  listing options={style=tcblatex,language=sh},
  every listing line={\textcolor{red}{\small\ttfamily\bfseries root \$> }}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{commandshell}
ls -al
cd /usr/lib
\end{commandshell}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

You can, of course, adjust the settings (like environment name and colours) to suit your needs.